# How to develop intuition to come up with Context Free Grammar?

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, context-free, formal-grammars, lexical-analysis

So i'm taking this class automata and complexity at georgia tech and we were given practice material for our exam.

one of the question is to give context free grammar for these two languages

[image]

[image]

and the answers are:

L1

[image]

L2

[image]

I can understand these and verify that these are indeed correct once I know the solution, but I'm finding it incredibly hard to even come close to coming up with them.

Does anyone have any advice on how to intuitively come up with CFGs

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: thank you, this is helpful! :)